# ajax code, jquery return false not working. tried other answers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a AJAX code and linked the php file, but the code is not accepting `return false;` function at the end. it is taking me to the action file. My ajax code

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

    var data = $("#form :input").serializeArray();

    $.post($("#form").attr("action"), data, function(info) { $("#result").html(info);});
});

$("#form").submit(function() {

    return false;
});
```

My index.php code

```
<?php

include('new.php');


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax practice</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="new.php" method="post" id="form">
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="Email" name="email"/><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">submit to database</button>
    </form>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

My php file

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax") or die ("couldnt connect to database.");


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    global $con;

    $title = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];


    $insert_user = "INSERT INTO ajax (title, email) VALUES ('$title', '$email')";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$insert_user);


    if ($run_user) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: What is inside new.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- NEVER name your submit button "submit" - it replaces/blocks the form.submit handler
  Change
  `<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">submit to database</button>`
  to
  `<button type="submit">submit to database</button>`
- If JS with handlers are in the head or before the objects they access, you need to wrap the handler in an onload - here I use `$(function() {....});`
- Canonical way is to use the submit event and NOT the click event - it also saves a handler:

To test: http://plungjan.name/SO/testajax/testajax.html

```
$(function() { // when page loads
  $("#form").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(info) {       
      $("#result").html(info);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this. Its still taking me to other php file.

Comment: Please update your question. Go to jsfiddle.net and add relevant HTML. To test the submit you can alas not use the snippet editor here since it does not allow submit

Comment: can we use jsfiddle for php as well?

Comment: Not needed - your main error is naming your submit button "submit

Comment: Tried the updated code. Its taking me to the new page. no errors found on  f12. it stoped updating my database as well

Comment: Did you remove name=submit and id=submit ?

Comment: yes i did. <button type="submit">submit to database</button>

Answer (score 0):

you have to prevent the default action of submit in first part of code that is in click function

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
#sumit is id for <input type="submit">
```

Hence when you do

```
  $('#submit').click(function() {});
```

Without preventDefault and do

```
#('#form').submit(function() {
    Return false;
 } //think this for your form
```

You contradict your code. You tell it to do and not do so it's confused

I advise you do

```
$('#form').on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({//ajax code});

      Return false;
    )};
```

Try this for your code

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var data = $('#form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
    )};
return false;
});
```

Comment: I tired this. 
$("#form").on("submit",function(e) {
 
  var data = $("#form :input").serializeArray();

 $.post($("#form").attr("action"), data, function(info) {
  $("#result").html(info);
  });
   Return false;
});

Still now working.

Comment: its still taking me to the other php page.

Comment: Is your script in an external file? Hope you liked the right jQuery cdn or file and you linked properly.

Comment: yes its an external file. i linked the correct jquery file. i checked. can you check my code and advice?